# Hugging Face Hub API swagger

Tags: swagger, huggingface, huggingface-hub

I am looking for, if it exist, the swagger of the api for interacting with ‘huggingface.co’. The API is described here:

https://huggingface.co/docs/hub/api

There is even a playground tool provided so I think there exist a swagger (maybe it is not a proper swagger, or the playground was manually implemented for each)

I have tried to look through the documentation and on the github repositories but couldn’t find it.

I found the following two swaggers:

```
api.endpoints.huggingface.cloud/openapi.json
github: /huggingface/datasets-server/blob/main/docs/source/openapi.json
```

However those are not for the "hub" but for the model and dataset APIs